# "am/remain/stay" as linking verbs or not

Tags: linking-verbs

> (1) *I **am** here.* [linking verb or not?]
>
> (2) *I **remain** here.* [linking verb or not?]
>
> (3) *I **stay** here.* [linking verb or not?]
>
> (1') *I **am** angry.* [linking verb]
>
> (2') *I **remain** angry.* [linking verb]
>
> (3') *I **stay** angry.* [linking verb]

In the latter three, "am", "remain" and "stay" are all linking verbs.

How about those verbs in the former three?

Are they linking verbs as in the latter three or are they not?

### EDIT

(In response to Adam's answer)

In Oxford Learner's Dictionaries, "[remain](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/remain?q=remain)" is shown to have four distinct meanings, the last of which is as follows

> 4 [intransitive] + adv./prep. to stay in the same place; to not leave
>
> *They remained in Mexico until June.*
>
> *The plane remained on the ground.*
>
> *She left, but I remained behind.*

All three "remained" in the example sentences here are replaceable with "was/were", but the dictionary doesn't categorize this kind of "remain" as a linking verb, given that the first meaning of the four is listed as a linking verb.

### EDIT

If "am" in "I am here" is a linking verb, then why is it not possible to say "I become here" or "I seem here". I mean, if "am" is a linking verb, shouldn't it be replaceable with another linking verb?

Comment: Answer to question in last Edit: No, because "linking verbs" are not freely substitutable. In the right context, one can construct equivalent sentences for practically any pair, but that's not unusual if the context is specific enough. "Linking verb" is a fiction meant to keep children from asking questions the teacher isn't clear on.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that "Linking Verb" is not defined precisely enough.

All the discussion so far has simply presupposed that there is such a category, and presumed that there was a good definition of it. Somewhere. But nobody's got one that works well enough, so far. Perhaps there isn't one.

"Linking verb" is a sort of translation of the Latin *copula* 'coupling', which referred to the Latin verb [*sum, esse, fūī, futūrus* 'be'](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=sum&la=la&can=sum0#lexicon). Everyone agrees that *be* is an English linking verb. But are there others?

Well, a replacement test won't work. *Be* is far too idiomatic for substituting it to prove anything.

The suggestion has been made that a linking verb connects the subject to some constituent after the verb, but exactly what kind of constituent, and what kind of connection is made, are not specified.

There are a lot of different kinds of phenomena (constructions and rules, for instance) that connect one part of a sentence with another. Verbs connect noun phrases (like the subject), and other kinds of phrases, depending on the meaning of the verb.

Verbs that can often cause confusion are Locatives, like *stand, lie, remain,* and *fall*, as in

- *At the top of the stairs stands a grandfather clock.*
- *The professor's grave lies next to his mother's.*
- *A lonely mesa rises east of Albuquerque.*
- *He remained at the wheel for three hours.*
- *A boundary falls on his property.*

Other verbs that can cause confusion are the Aspectual verbs, like *start, finish, stop, continue,* and *remain*. Note that *remain* belongs to both classes; they are not disjoint. Language mostly doesn't have neat boundaries.

- *He started/stopped being depressed around November.*
- *He continued being depressed all year.*
- *He remained depressed all year.*

They take various complement types -- *being* is required with a predicate adjective for complements of *continue,* but it's forbidden for *remain* -- but they're complements, not adjuncts. Aspectual verbs have very little independent meaning; they're close to, but not quite, real auxiliary verbs like *be*. That's probly why they cause the trouble.

The definition of a grammar school term like "linking verb" (which is taught to children instead of "auxiliary verb" because *auxiliary* is too big a word) is vague on purpose. It's for children, so it doesn't need to be any more precise than the definition of "bogeyman". Your teachers very likely didn't understand it, anyway, because they'd been taught by teachers who didn't, either, and **they**, in turn, were also.

Answer (score 0):

Linking verbs connect the subject to additional info describing the subject (state of being, quality, etc.). As a quick pointer, all forms of *be* are always linking verbs. ([source](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/linkingverb.htm))

> 1. I am here. (linking—*am* is a form of *be*)
> 2. I remain here. (linking—*remain* describes the temporal aspect of where you are)
> 3. I stay here. (linking—*stay* also describes the temporal aspect of where you are)

Referencing the source again, if you can replace the verb with *am*, *are*, or *is* and the sentence still makes sense, it is most likely a linking verb.

In your last question, *become* and *seem* are, interestingly enough, linking verbs as well. Although *here* doesn't fit in these cases, the verbs are still linking.

Comment: Please read the 'edit' and let me know if you think the dictionary is wrong or that it turns out not as simply as you seem to suggest it is.

Comment: @JK2 I have edited my answer. It seems I rushed through it too quickly. Your edits are correct.

Comment: I'm not sure how reliable your "continuous aspect test" could be, given that you actually can say "I'm being stupid" (when 'am' is a linking verb in "I'm stupid").

Comment: Anyways, please read my second edit, and let me know what you think.

Comment: @JK2 So I'm definitely confusing myself by this point. I sincerely apologize. All three verbs _are_ linking verbs. The last two are very strange, but they are linking nonetheless.

Comment: If the "remain" in (2) is a linking verb, how do you differentiate it from the three "remained" in the first EDIT?

Comment: @JK2 The problem here is that _remain_ is one of the few verbs that can be both types. Sadly, I can't find any solid proof online to show you it's linking here, but at this point I firmly believe it is acting as both by sometimes describing a state of being and sometimes the act of doing nothing.

Comment: I agree that "remain" is one of the rare verbs that can be both types. And aren't "be" and "stay" also those rare verbs? Now, if the only verbs that can take the place of "be" in (1) are these rare verbs such as "remain" and "stay" as in (2) and (3), respectively, and if other linking verbs such as "seem" or "become" may not take the place of "be" in (1), then shouldn't we conclude that the verbs in (1) to (3) are NOT used as linking verbs?

Comment: *"I live here"*: not a linking verb. *"I am here"*: the sentence makes sense. *"I write fast"*: not a linking verb. *"I am fast"*: the sentence makes sense. I don't think that's a very useful criterion.